# Is it safe to build React project on remote server

Tags: npm, node-modules, vps

I was wondering if it is safe to build a react project on the production server.
i managed to set up git `post-receive` hook like this:

```sh
TARGET="/work_dir"
...
       git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f $BRANCH
       cd "$TARGET"
       npm install
       npm run build
       pm2 restart
```

this way i can simply push everything to production just by:

```
git push prod release
```

the above script is of course a simplified image but you get the idea of what I'm trying to do.
It works but is it safe? Can installing external node modules on production server cause problems?